# MongoDB: sort and limit query with 'or' operator on embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Having the following data structure:

```
"feature": {
  "site": {
    "subjects": [ 
      {                   
        "subject_id" : 1,
        "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
      }
    ],
  },
  "mobile": {            
    "subjects" : [ 
      {                    
        "subject_id" : 1,
        "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
      }, 
      {                    
        "subject_id" : 2,
        "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wish to make a query to get all features that have subject with id 1 embedded, either in 'mobile' or 'site'. With this query:

```
db.features.find( { $or: [ { site.subjects.subject_id: 1 }, { mobile.subjects.subject_id:1 } ] } )
```

How can such a query be sorted by (mobile or site).subjects.time?

Comment: Which one are we supposed to sort by if both exist?

Comment: let's say we prioritise 'site'

Comment: Was there something in the supplied answer that does not answer your question?

Comment: @NeilLunn your answer is awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general case with your "sort" problem is that there needs to be a "specific" field value on which to sort on. Really the best performance is gained by including that field in your document as your create or update. You cannot "conditionally sort" using find alone.

If you need to do the "dynamically" then you are looking to "project" something in this case that matches your conditions, and for that you need the aggregation framework.

There are some pitfalls here, as when doing manipulation on documents to come to this end, the process of manipulation is not as forgiving as the general query logic. Mostly when dealing with arrays you need to make sure that there are no empty contents while you are working with them. A few extra samples based on your sample data gives a guide to working with the problems:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b49853c1a7b867c4541482"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4ccb6fbc9071ff8fc2d5b"),
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4cf58c4e3a228da24c225"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4d03bc4e3a228da24c227"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T18:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T04:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The first document is your basic sample, but the other vary in some means for a specific purpose to demonstrate some possible problems, not necessarily indicative of your own data of course.

The second document deliberately omits the "site" key and with the third, though the "site" is present, the "subject_id" will not match the condition for consideration. Yes it is an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition for document selection, but we are taking this further here to only consider those "sub-document" elements that also meet the criteria. Meaning here that a "date" to sort on or even "filtered" content will not consider any of the items there that to not have the required `"subject_id": 1`.

First looking at just creating a value that you can sort on based on the conditions:

```js
db.features.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
         "$or": [ 
             { "site.subjects.subject_id": 1 }, 
             { "mobile.subjects.subject_id": 1 }
         ]
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "scopy": { "$ifNull": ["$site.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] },
        "mcopy": { "$ifNull": ["$mobile.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$scopy" },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "scopy": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$scopy.subject_id", 1 ] },
                "$scopy.time",
                false
            ]
        },
        "mcopy": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "scopy": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "site": { "$first": "$site" },
        "mobile": { "$first": "$mobile" },
        "mcopy": { "$first": "$mcopy" },
        "scopy": { "$first": "$scopy" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$mcopy" },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "scopy": 1,
        "mcopy": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$mcopy.subject_id", 1 ] },
                "$mcopy.time",
                false
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "mcopy": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "site": { "$first": "$site" },
        "mobile": { "$first": "$mobile" },
        "mcopy": { "$first": "$mcopy" },
        "scopy": { "$first": "$scopy" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "site": { 
            "$ifNull": [ 
                "$site", 
                { "$const": { "subjects": [] } }
            ]
        },
        "mobile": {
            "$ifNull": [
                "$mobile",
                { "$const": { "subjects": [] } }
            ]
        },
        "best": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$mcopy", "$scopy" ] },
                "$mcopy",
                "$scopy"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "best": -1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1
    }}
])
```

And that should order the documents with the preference on the "time" value from "site" where that one has the most recent value. The last document in the sample should come out first.

Now if you are actually asking to "limit" as in your title, which I presume means "filter" to the actual "matching" results, then you do things just a little differently:

```js
db.features.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
         "$or": [ 
             { "site.subjects.subject_id": 1 }, 
             { "mobile.subjects.subject_id": 1 }
         ]
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "wsite": { "$ifNull": ["$site.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] },
        "wmobile": { "$ifNull": ["$mobile.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wsite" },
    { "$project": {
        "wsite": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$wsite.subject_id", 1 ] },
                "$wsite",
                false
            ]
        },
        "wmobile": 1
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$addToSet": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$max": "$wsite.time" },
        "csite": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wsite" },
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [ 
            { "wsite": { "$ne": false } },
            { "csite": 1 }
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$push": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$first": "$msite" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wmobile" },
    { "$project": {
        "wsite": 1,
        "wmobile": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$wmobile.subject_id", 1 ] },
                "$wmobile",
                false
            ]
        },
        "msite": 1,
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$first": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$addToSet": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$first": "$msite" },
        "mmobile": { "$max": "$wmobile.time" },
        "cmobile": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wmobile" },
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [
            { "wmobile": { "$ne": false } },
            { "cmobile": 1 }
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$first": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$push": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$first": "$msite" },
        "mmobile": { "$first": "$mmobile" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "site": {
            "subjects": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$wsite", { "$const": [false] } ] },
                    { "$const": [] },
                    "$wsite"
                ]
            }
        },
        "mobile": {
            "subjects": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$wmobile", { "$const": [false] } ] },
                    { "$const": [] },
                    "$wmobile"
                ]
            }
        },
        "best": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$mmobile", "$msite" ] },
                "$mmobile",
                "$msite"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "best": -1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1
    }}
])
```

A bit cleaner with features from MongoDB 2.6, where most of the array filtering can be done within a single stage:

```js
db.features.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
         "$or": [ 
             { "site.subjects.subject_id": 1 }, 
             { "mobile.subjects.subject_id": 1 }
         ]
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "wsite": {
            "$let": {
                "vars": {            
                    "list": { "$setDifference": [
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                 "input": {
                                     "$ifNull": [ 
                                         "$site.subjects",
                                         { "$literal": [false] }
                                     ]
                                 },
                                 "as": "el",
                                 "in": {
                                     "$cond": [
                                         { "$eq": [ "$$el.subject_id", 1 ] },
                                         "$$el",
                                         false
                                     ]
                                 }
                             }
                        },
                        [false]
                    ]}
                },
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$$list" }, 0 ] },
                        { "$literal": [false] },
                        "$$list"
                    ]
                }
            }    
        },
        "wmobile": {
            "$let": {
                "vars": {            
                    "list": { "$setDifference": [
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                 "input": {
                                     "$ifNull": [ 
                                         "$mobile.subjects",
                                         { "$literal": [false] }
                                     ]
                                 },
                                 "as": "el",
                                 "in": {
                                     "$cond": [
                                         { "$eq": [ "$$el.subject_id", 1 ] },
                                         "$$el",
                                         false
                                     ]
                                 }
                             }
                        },
                        [false]
                    ]}
                },
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$$list" }, 0 ] },
                        { "$literal": [false] },
                        "$$list"
                    ]
                }
            }    
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wsite" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$push": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "fsite": { "$max": "$wsite.time" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$wmobile" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$first": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$push": "$wmobile" },
        "fsite": { "$first": "$fsite" },
        "fmobile": { "$max": "$wmobile.time" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "site": {
            "subjects": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$allElementsTrue": "$wsite" },
                    "$wsite",
                    { "$literal": [] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "mobile": {
            "subjects": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$allElementsTrue": "$wmobile" },
                    "$wmobile",
                    { "$literal": [] }
                ]
            }
        },
        "best": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$fmobile", "$fsite" ] },
                "$fmobile",
                "$fsite"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "best": -1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1
    }}
])
```

The main things to consider in those statements fall into the handling of arrays. Various operations here that "require" an array for input will fail dismally if no actual array exists. The even worse case is when it comes to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), which will if presented with a completely "empty" array, will just remove that document from the pipeline completely as it considers there was nothing to "expand".

The main "counter" for this is [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/). This essentially tests for the "presence" of a field and either returns it or the alternate result which is the second argument. Each case uses this to return an array with a single element `[false]`, which means that any subsequent [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) not only does not "blow up" due to the lack of a field that is an array, but also does not consider the current document to be empty and thus remove it.

```js
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "scopy": { "$ifNull": ["$site.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] },
        "mcopy": { "$ifNull": ["$mobile.subjects", { "$const": [false] }] }
    }},
```

The first sample keeps the original fields as it is just going to return them "as is" after working out how the documents are going to be sorted. But as with the copies, or otherwise "filtering" only the matching results, these are going to be manipulated in some way to both "filter" and determine which date to use for sorting.

Without changing the existing arrays the first example is relatively simple. Here what you want to do is basically "sort" the arrays in the documents, one at a time after you unwind in order to get the most recent date.

```js
    { "$unwind": "$mcopy" },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "scopy": 1,
        "mcopy": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$mcopy.subject_id", 1 ] },
                "$mcopy.time",
                false
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "mcopy": -1 } },
```

The additional thing being done in this version is making sure that the dates that will be considered comes from a "sub-document" that matches the criteria. If not then the date is replaced with `false` which will be sorted to the bottom of the list.

The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) here then uses the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to pick up the most recent items after sorting. Doing that process for each array now gives two dates to compare so you can decide which one to sort on at the end.

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "site": { "$first": "$site" },
        "mobile": { "$first": "$mobile" },
        "mcopy": { "$first": "$mcopy" },
        "scopy": { "$first": "$scopy" }
    }},
```

In the "filtering" approach, not only is the comparison being made to see if the "date" considered is going to match the criteria, but in fact the whole "sub-document" element is considered and removed if it would not match.

Care is taken here to not "destroy" the document completely and not leave an empty array or otherwise remove the document if nothing in that array would match. This explains the process of using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) then [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for the comparison and "size" of the matched result which comes next.

These are the put to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator as you can reasonably presume the results to be unqiue, and also using [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) in this case to find the largest "date" value. This also condenses any `false` values to a single entry.

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$addToSet": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$max": "$wsite.time" },
        "csite": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
```

Only then can you [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) again and safely use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter out anything that was `false`. The care being taken here to not remove the document if there was in fact only a single value of `false` in that array. The final "grouping" there should now have either the filtered results or just a single value of `false` under each array.

```js
    { "$unwind": "$wsite" },
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [ 
            { "wsite": { "$ne": false } },
            { "csite": 1 }
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$push": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "msite": { "$first": "$msite" }
    }},
```

In the final listing, we are taking advantage of new things that can be done with features implemented in MongoDB 2.6.

Various pipeline stages from the previous listing are "combined" there as the new [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator allows some array processing without using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Basically the same evaluation is done on the matching conditions, and the `false` values returned are "filtered out" by the comparison of [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to an array that only contains `[false]`.

Any "empty" arrays that contain no matches are then tested with the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator, where empty would return a size of `0`. The conditions here then just replace those empty arrays with a single `[false]` as was done before.

The reason for the last part is that you still need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to get the largest or [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) "date" value from each array.

```js
    { "$unwind": "$wsite" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "wsite": { "$push": "$wsite" },
        "wmobile": { "$first": "$wmobile" },
        "fsite": { "$max": "$wsite.time" }
    }},
```

From here the different approaches to coding this up are mostly similar. Now that you have the dates to compare from each array you just need to determine which one is the most recent or other logical comparison:

```js
        "best": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$fmobile", "$fsite" ] },
                "$fmobile",
                "$fsite"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "best": -1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "site": 1,
        "mobile": 1
    }}
```

The resulting date value is then used to **`$sort`** the final results and then just passed on to **`$project`** to remove our projected field for the date comparison.

In either case, the order of results by comparison from the sample documents is "Fourth", "First", "Second" and "Third". The "Fourth" document has the most recent date on the preferred "site" field so it is the top result. The "First" sample has the next largest date that would be chosen.

The "Second" and "Third" actually choose the same date value even where both do not have a possible matching entry for the "site" field. The only reason for the order here is actually just the document `_id` value which is how the documents came into the pipeline.

Without "filtering" the arrays the output actually is:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4d03bc4e3a228da24c227"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T18:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T04:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4cf58c4e3a228da24c225"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4ccb6fbc9071ff8fc2d5b"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [ ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b49853c1a7b867c4541482"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
            {
                "subject_id" : 1,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
            },
            {
                "subject_id" : 2,
                "time" : ISODate("2014-06-24T23:44:29.759Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And with filtering:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4d03bc4e3a228da24c227"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T18:38:29.751Z")
             }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T04:14:29.758Z")
             }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b49853c1a7b867c4541482"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T06:38:29.751Z")
             }
        ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
             }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4ccb6fbc9071ff8fc2d5b"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [ ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
             }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b4cf58c4e3a228da24c225"),
    "site" : {
        "subjects" : [ ]
    },
    "mobile" : {
        "subjects" : [
             {
                 "subject_id" : 1,
                 "time" : ISODate("2014-06-28T16:14:29.758Z")
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

The main case here is that while it is possible to "project" a field like this for comparison it is generally better to keep it in your document as then you have something to quickly sort on without the overhead of constructing that first for each document.

If you do indeed need to "filter" the array results to those that would match the conditions then you would indeed be doing this, as the projection available with the positional `$` operator will not support matches with "two" arrays.

At any rate, at least this serves as a sample for more advanced usage of document "re-shaping" with the aggregation framework and shows the possibilities there. But like all complex operations this does come at a cost, so where performance is concerned you should design your data around that.